# How to limit all columns in a database using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an image gallery system, and I want to know how to limit/show all image uploaded into the gallery/database table. I normally don't know how this is done so I usually use a number greater than the number of columns in the database to show all my columns. I will love to know how this is done in other to change my method of doing this.

**HERE IS MY CODE BELOW;**

```
<?php
  $image_id = $the_image = $image_des = $time_uploaded = "";
  $gallery = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM gallery ORDER BY time_uploaded DESC LIMIT 9000");
  while ($pick = mysqli_fetch_array($gallery, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $image_id = $pick['id'];
    $the_image = $pick['image'];
    $image_des = $pick['description'];
    $time_uploaded = $pick['time_uploaded'];
    echo '<div class="nicdark_margin100">';
      echo '<a href="../img/gallery/'.$the_image.'" title="'.$image_des.'"><img alt="" class="nicdark_radius nicdark_opacity" src="../img/gallery/'.$the_image.'" width="100" height="100" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    echo ' </div>';                    
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't require a LIMIT field in the query. So to get all results

```
SELECT * FROM gallery ORDER BY time_uploaded DESC
```

However, if you're trying to do pagination, you can combine LIMIT and OFFSET

```
## First Page of 25 images
SELECT * FROM gallery ORDER BY time_uploaded DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
## Second Page of 25 images (offset by 25)
SELECT * FROM gallery ORDER BY time_uploaded DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 25
```

For more info, see

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Comment: @Dev.aaron so how about you positive his answer as accepted?

Comment: @Dev.aaron so i'm positiving your question, I also had that doubt, cheers.